# Get remote ip-address with UDP and dgram in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp

Is it possible to get the ip-address of client that sent a UDP-request to my node-application?

The application is used in my local network and I want to filter requests depending on addresses. 
When I try to use the address provided in the rinfo-object while getting an message-event, I just get the routers address, which didn't help me much.

I know that there is the possibility to get the clients ip-address via request.headers['X-Forwarded-For'] when I use nodes net-library, but it doesn't seem there is something like that in dgram.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can use the rinfo object for Event: 'message'. The rinfo object has fields for this: rinfo.address + ":" + rinfo.port

Please see here: http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to use the rinfo-object but it only contains the ip-address of the router. I need the address of the client that started the request just like the request.headers['X-Forwared-For'] in nodes net-lib.

Comment: Here is the quote from nodejs.org (http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html): "rinfo is an object with the sender's address information and the number of bytes in the datagram.". So, the rinfo should contain the IP address of the sender. If the sender is sitting behind a NAT, then it might use the router's IP address and in that case, I am not sure, if anything would help.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I always get the IP-address of the router. The problem is not inside my code but of my network-configuration. Thank you!